# Аутентификация/Идентификация и сессионность в SelfHost

Tags: c#, сессия, asp.net-web-api, service

Есть служба выполняющая роль сервера.
Хостинг веб приложения производится средствами `SelfHost`.

Необходимо что-бы каждый пользователь который попытается получить доступ к ресурсу был аутентифицирован и получил лицензию на время работы с ресурсом (на время сессии).

Из этого вытекает 2 вопроса.

**1**. Как аутентифицировать?

**2**. Как удержать сеанс пользователя (сформировать сессию)?

Ответ на вопрос **1**, как мне кажется, я уже нашел.

```
class ServiceSelfHostConfiguration : HttpSelfHostConfiguration
{
    public ServiceSelfHostConfiguration(string baseAddress)
         : base(baseAddress)
    { }

    public ServiceSelfHostConfiguration(Uri baseAddress)
        : base(baseAddress)
    { }


    protected override BindingParameterCollection OnConfigureBinding(HttpBinding httpBinding)
    {
        httpBinding.Security.Mode = HttpBindingSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
        httpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;//к примеру
        return base.OnConfigureBinding(httpBinding);
    }
}
```

Но сервис не инициирует сессию. При каждом запросе браузер проходит аутентификацию повторно.

Поэтому остался вопрос 2: **Как связать аутентификацию с сессионностью средствами SelfHost? Как работать с сессиями в проекте запущенном под SelfHost?**

Заранее спасибо! И извините за, возможно, плохое понимание веб технологий.

*p.s. На мой взгляд, можно написать что-то вроде `MessageHandler`'a который будет проводить аутентификацию и формировать сессию самостоятельно. Но, как мне кажется, существует более простой способ сделать это.*

Comment: cookie - слышали? :)

Comment: Обычно ключи сессии ложат в cookie после аутенфикации.

Comment: А аутенфикация обычно через метод HTTP POST, аля login=root, pass=12345

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич Есть виды аутентификации которые работают без POST запросов. Пример: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chiranth/2013/09/20/ntlm-want-to-know-how-it-works/

Comment: Никто и не спорит. Я Вам даю простой вариант, самый распространенный. Лично я писал и через SOAP. Но Вы как бы про HTTP задали вопрос. Хотя SOAP оно тоже поверх http.

Comment: Я немного не понял в чем заключается ваш простой вариант. В ручном написании логики сессии и аутентификации, про которое я внизу вопроса курсивом написал? Если нет никакого более простого варианта, то я и планирую так поступить.

Comment: У Вас в вопросе http :) В http всего то ничего способов передачи данных на сервер, и самый распространенный при авторизации - POST. Это ответ на Ваш вопрос. Скорее всего на C# уже есть готовые библиотеки, таких тонкостей не знаю.

Comment: Извините, возможно я немного не точно описал вопрос. Поправил.